# Strange groupby/Dataframe behavior with list ()

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I needed to build a dict of selected values in groups built from a dataframe ("grouped"). idcolumn was a list of one string ["column_name"] (I made it a list because at some point, I needed to append various other strings/columns name for operations using labels).

so I used as a mean to retrieve the groups this statement:

```
grouped.get_group(k).loc[:,idcolumn]
```

which works perfectly identically to

```
grouped.get_group(k).loc[:,idcolumn[0]]
```

outputting a dataframe of the selected data with ["column_name"] as header.

My complete expression was:

```
dict_to_build= {k: list(grouped.get_group(k).loc[:,idcolumn]) for k in grouped.groups.keys() }
```

but I had a very strange error.
the built dict contains all the keys but as a unique value "column_name". 
While if I use

```
dict_to_build= {k: list(grouped.get_group(k).loc[:,idcolumn[0]) for k in grouped.groups.keys() }
```

The dict is perfectly ok.

as examplified like this:

```
In [115]: pde=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,1,2,3], "column_name":["a","b","c","d","e","f"]})

In [116]: pde
Out[116]: 
   a column_name
0  1           a
1  2           b
2  3           c
3  1           d
4  2           e
5  3           f

In [117]: grouped=pde.groupby[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-117-b504dadfee12>", line 1, in <module>
    grouped=pde.groupby[1]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable


In [118]: grouped=pde.groupby("a")

In [119]: grouped.get_group(1).loc[:,"column_name"]
Out[119]: 
0    a
3    d
Name: column_name, dtype: object

In [120]: list(grouped.get_group(1).loc[:,"column_name"])
Out[120]: ['a', 'd']

In [121]: list(grouped.get_group(1).loc[:,["column_name"]])
Out[121]: ['column_name']
```

Can someone enlighten me about what is happening? It is absolutely strange for me. Does the problem comes from dataframes, loc with list as a parameter, or the list function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is

```
grouped.get_group(1).loc[:,"column_name"]
```

returns a Series while

```
grouped.get_group(1).loc[:,["column_name"]]
```

returns a Dataframe.

When you do list(Series), it returns the values of the Series, while when you do a list(Dataframe), it returns the columns of the df, in this case 'column_name'.

Comment: Makes perfect sense;) Thanks a lot!